# Best practice for add items to adapter from LiveData.observe()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I have DAO method returned `LiveData<List<Category>>`:

```
LiveData<List<Category>> listLiveData = categoryDao.getAll();
```

After that I need set this data to my Adapter:

```
listLiveData.observe(this, categories -> {
      if (categories == null || categories.isEmpty()) {
            price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories);
            categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickHandler());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        }
 });
```

if I have not data in DB I show button for update(get data from server and insert to DB).
if I have data I create adapter and set data to it.

After that if I insert some `Category` to DB I get this:

1. triggered observe method and get all categories
2. create new adapter with this data

I think it is very bad practice(create a new adapter for update each item) and I can some way:

1. Change my adapter and add method `addData(List<Category> categories);`

   in onCreateView I create adapter: `categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(new ArrayList());`

then when I get data in `observe` method I add it to adapter:

```
adapter.addData(categories);
```

and into `addData` method in loop check each item and if not exist add to list and notify data.

2. change method

   LiveData> listLiveData = categoryDao.getAll();

to

```
LiveData<Category> category = categoryDao.getLast();
```

and add this item to `observe` method. But I have 2 problems: 1 - How can I add firstly all data? I must implement 2 methods `getAll`(call wen create adapter) and `getLast`(call for each insert in DB). 2. How can I write this `getLast` method?

3. correct way that you will advise me :)

Comment: @ pskink 1. I do not have pagination. and this is a slightly different task (pagination) and to solve this problem in this way, I think not quite right. 2. I do not want to use the approach MVVM.

Comment: I want to understand how this is implemented with livedata because if I subscribed to the method observe I always get all rows if something changed in this table

Comment: At start of a fragment I want to receive all elements which are in the table. and after if for example in the background I add a new element so that it is added and appeared in the list

Comment: LiveData gives me this opportunity (itself follows the changes) but if I inserted 1 record it in the obser method I get all the table entries + 1 new which I inserted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your first step is right, you should create adapter only once in a lifecycle of `Fragment` or `Activity` and set the value(`list`) to adapter whenever you need to change dataset.
- You should use `getAll()` method and it is best practice because you have data in local database and that doesn't take longer. If you have long data set then you should use pagination where only limited no. of items are fetched at a time. That can be achieved using `LIMIT` clause queries in sqlite.
- And then use notifyDatasetChanged() method. If you want to show a smooth animation for newly inserted items use `DiffUtil` class to compare list and notify adapter accordingly.

To know how to use `DiffUtil`, check this out https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Hope this helps.

Comment: the logic is this.
1. I checked the data in the database and if there is one uploaded. (for example 3 elements)
2. In the background thread, I added an entry to the table and should see how it was added to the list.
3. These records will be 1-20 . Is pagination relevant here? and most likely I will add one record every 5 seconds

Comment: Pagination is requited when you have large set of data that requires more than 2 seconds to fetch it. As you just mentioned one element each 5 seconds. You should consider pagination because after a while your list might contain more than 1000 items that will slow down your app.

Comment: I say it will have a maximum of 20 elements. just open the list and periodically every 5 seconds and maybe 1 second will be added item to the background. but there will not be 1,000 of them even 100 (always 1-20 items)

Comment: then just `get all items` and invoke `adapter.modifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Comment: Well, to begin with, remove all the elements that are already in the sheet and then dovat all the new ones?

Comment: you mean in list view? then yes, there is no issue. Because at a time only visible item gets drawn. lets say there are 100 items in list but list view can only show 10 then only 10 will be drawn.

Comment: Man, I hate the need for pagination, wen cursors would have worked just fine.